# simple projectile motion problem solving equation

Tags: projective-module

a stone is thrown with a velocity of 20m/s at an elevation of angle A, given by tan A = 3/4, what horizontal distance does it cover in 2 sec, and what is its height then above the horizontal plane through the point of projection?

solution:

r(right) Ux=VcosA=(4/5)V

r(down)  Uy=VsinA=(3/5)V

R(right)distance=speed x time

height=(3/5)x V x t
=(3/5) 20 x t
=12 x 2
= 24 m (BUT answer is 4 m??)

distance= (4/5)Vt
=(4/5)20t
=16t
=16x2
=32 m (correct approach??)

Comment: I would've edited your question, [Please Fix $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Physics SE abused, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For the height you are expected to include gravity, so there should be a term $-\frac 12gt^2$.  For the horizontal distance you are fine.

Comment: height=(3/5)x V x t −0.5gt^2 =(3/5) 20 x t - 19.4 =4.4 m

Comment: You have two mistakes in the last.  It looks like you are taking $g=9.7 m/s^2$, when $9.8$ is closer and your answer sheet expects $10$. Second, your first term is not calculated correctly if it is $23.8$ as it appears.

Comment: with g = 9.8 m/s2
height=(3/5)x V x t −0.5gt^2 =(3/5) 20 x 2 - 0.5x9.8x4 
= 24 - 19.6 = 4.4 m


with g = 10 m/s2
height=(3/5)x V x t −0.5gt^2 =(3/5) 20 x 2 - 0.5x10x4 
= 24 - 20 = 4.0 m

Comment: Thanks for your highlights